# Simple Objective C program - It can't be this complex

Tags: objective-c

I'm in the process of learning Objective C and decided to create a simple command line program. The idea is that is asks you for your name and then displays it backwards, capitalizing the first letter of each word. I got it done but the solution seems overly complex.  I can't help but feel there is a better way.

```
            char word [256];
    printf("What is your name: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s",word);

    // Convert the char array to NSString
    NSString * inputString = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString: word encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //This will be our output string
    //NSString *nameReversed = [[NSString alloc] init];  //alloc, init are needed to create an instance of this object
    NSString *nameReversed = @"";

    // Make inputString all lower case
    inputString = [inputString lowercaseString];

    // Get length of inputString and type cast it as an int and decrement by one
    int length = (int)([inputString length])-1;

    BOOL foundSpace = NO;

    for (int i = 0; i<=(length); i++) {
        // Setup the range
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange(length-i,1);

        // Get the a char from the input string
        NSString *inputChar = [inputString substringWithRange:range];

        // If this is the first char then make it upper case
        if (i==0) {
            inputChar = [inputChar capitalizedString];
        }

        // See if the last char was a space and if so make this char upper case
        if (foundSpace){
            foundSpace = NO;  // Reset foundSpace
            // Set this char to upper case
            inputChar = [inputChar capitalizedString];
        }

        // See if this char is a space.  If so, we'll need to convert the next char to upper case
        if ([inputChar  isEqual: @" "]) {
            foundSpace = YES;
        }

        // Add the char to nameReversed
        nameReversed = [nameReversed stringByAppendingString:inputChar];

    }

    printf("%s \n", [nameReversed UTF8String]);
```

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: Why is the format flag for scanf() "[^\n]"?

Comment: That's not a format flag.  It's a conversion.  The full conversion specification is `%[^\n]`.  It tells `scanf` to parse all characters up to but not including a `\n`.  The `s` after the conversion specification in the format string tells `scanf` to match input character `s` exactly.  This will fail.  This is a bug in RicH's format string.

Answer (score 2):

Your program doesn't handle composed character sequences properly.

Also, `capitalizedString` will capitalize the first letter of each word in the string.  So you can just call it once.

```
static NSString *reversedString(NSString *string) {
    NSMutableString *reversed = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:string.length];
    [string enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)
        options:NSStringEnumerationReverse
            | NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
        usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
        [reversed appendString:substring];
    }];
    return reversed;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSData *inputData = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput] readDataToEndOfFile];
        NSString *original = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:inputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSString *reversed = reversedString(original);
        NSString *reversedAndCapitalized = [reversed capitalizedString];
        printf("%s\n", reversedAndCapitalized.UTF8String);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In a real app I'd probably add a category on `NSString` defining a `reversedString` method, instead of making it a free function.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!  It will take me some time to parse through your version as it's beyond me at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume the input is in ascii encoding.

```
char word [256];
printf("What is your name: ");
scanf("%[^\n]s", word);

// reverse
for (NSInteger i=0,j=strlen(word)-1; i<j; i++,j--) {
    char tmp = word[i];
    word[i] = word[j];
    word[j] = tmp;
}

NSString *str0 = [NSString stringWithCString:word encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", [str0 capitalizedString]);
```

Comment: Your approach of using a char array was what I had in mind initially but couldn't seem to get it working.  Thanks for your help!